Retries for Certs rejected by the OPCUA server
We use Milo to create a client and establish connection with the OPCUA server. If the server rejects the Cert, then the client receives a response with the message Bad Security Check Failed. I believe Milo does automatic retry and backs off its attempts exponentially until it's attempting every ~16 seconds. I have few questions on the retries -

Is there a configuration that allows us to configure the max retries or duration?
Does the retries ever stop i.e is there a max retry limit in terms of number of retries or after x amount of time?

Tried  reviewing the logs and reading the documentation/code

No, it will keep retrying, and the back-off is not configurable.
It will stop if you call OpcUaClient::disconnect.
